# How to print a pattern using AWK?

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I need to find in file word that matches regex pattern.

So if in line, i have:

```
00:10:20,918  I [AbstractAction.java] - register | 0.0.0.0 | {GW_CHANNEL=AA, PWD=********, ID=777777, GW_USER=BB, NUM=3996, SYSTEM_USER=OS, LOGIC_ID=0}
```

> ```
>  awk -F' ' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~ /GW_USER/ && /GW_CHANNEL/){print $5 " " $i} } }'
> ```

Print only:

```
 register GW_USER=BB
```

I wonna get:

```
register GW_USER=BB GW_CHANNEL=AA
```

How to print GW_USER and GW_CHANNEL columns?

Comment: what do you mean? You dont need number after that pattern? In your example where does cc comes from?

Comment: I changed my question and add example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have name=value pairs in your input, it's a good idea to create an array that maps the names to the values and then print by name:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/{[^}]+/) {
    str = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
    split(str,arr,/[ ,=]+/)
    delete n2v
    for (i=1; i in arr; i+=2) {
        n2v[arr[i]] = arr[i+1]
    }
    print $5, fmt("GW_USER"), fmt("GW_CHANNEL")
}
function fmt(name) { return (name "=" n2v[name]) }
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
register GW_USER=BB GW_CHANNEL=AA
```

that way you trivially print or do anything else you want with any other field in future.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` condition isn't looking right, you can use regex alternation:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~ /GW_USER|GW_CHANNEL/) print $5, $i } }' file
```

There is no need to use `-F" "` and `" "` in print as that is default field separator.

Your condition:

```
if($i ~ /GW_USER/ && /GW_CHANNEL/)
```

Will match `FW_USER` against `$i` but will match `GW_CHANNEL` in whole line.

Comment: 00:10:20,918  I [AbstractAction.java] - register | 0.0.0.0 | {GW_CHANNEL=AA, PWD=********, ID=777777, GW_USER=BB, NUM=3996, SYSTEM_USER=OS, LOGIC_ID=0}

Comment: /GW_USER|GW_CHANNEL/ - OR.

Comment: I wonna get:
register GW_USER=BB GW_CHANNEL=AA

Comment: Sorry didn't understand any of your comments. I suggest you edit your question and provide a sample data with your expected output.